# Not printing the ID, rather printing 'Array'?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, function, output

In my code, it should create a link for every ID leading to the corresponding page, but it leads to the page ?ID=Array instead of ?ID=ID

This is my code, you can view it here: http://pirates-online-rewritten.com/testblog.php

```
<?php
include "connect.php";
$ids = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM Blogs ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10");
while($id=mysql_fetch_assoc($ids)){
echo "<a href='http://www.pirates-online-rewritten.com/blog.php?ID=", $id, "'>Test</a><br />";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be `$id['ID']` instead of `$id`

Like this..

```
<?php
include "connect.php";
$ids = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM Blogs ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10");
while($id=mysql_fetch_array($ids)){ //<--- Changed to fetch_array
    echo "<a href='http://www.pirates-online-rewritten.com/blog.php?ID=", $id['ID'], "'>Test</a><br />";
}
```

---

This (`mysql_*`) extension is deprecated as of `PHP 5.5.0`, and will be removed in the future. Instead, **Prepared Statements** of [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [`PDO_MySQL`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) extension should be used to ward off SQL Injection attacks !